# Latest iTunes connect build not showing in TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I distributed the first build version of my app to internal testers with iTunes Connect and successfully installed on internal tester's devices. Now, I've uploaded the second build via iTunes Connect. My internal testers have received the email that build 2 is available and clicked on the button to view it in TestFlight, but when TestFlight opens only build 1 shows available to install.

Is there something else that I need to do to make build 2 available to testers, or does it just take some time for it to show up in TestFlight even after the testers get the email that it's available?

Comment: just ran into this, i'm wondering if it has to do with versioning. i started with version 0.1 incrementing the build number each time worked fine. last night i tried bumping version to 0.2 and restarting build number to 1 (first build of 0.2 version). got the itunes connect notification the build was ready, but it does not appear in test flight. i'll try these steps when i can login to itunes connect, thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've found that sometimes I've needed to toggle the 'TestFlight Beta Testing' switch to get everything to work.

UPDATE: iTunesConnect has been updated since the above answer.  Now to reset it you should do the following steps:

1. Select the 'Not Available for Testing' then tap save.

[image]

2. Hit the 'Select Version to Test' on the right hand side.  Select the version you want to test and then hit 'OK'.
3. Finally hit save and then tap the 'Start Testing' button.
   [image]

Now you should be good to go!

## 2018 UPDATE

Itunes connect seems to have changed again. The method above is no longer available. One solution us to expire the build, re-upload, and start testing again. To expire a build, select the build being tested (in the test flight section) the click expire in the top right corner. It should look something like this:
[image: Expire build]

This seems to remove the build from TestFlight and you will need to upload a new build. Not optimal, but I can't find another method right now.

Comment: @YuriSidorov it looks like they've updated iTunesConnect. I'll updated my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: I had to remove myself and reinvite myself as a tester. then click on the link from the email on the device you are using.

Comment: where is that switch now?

Comment: Ditto to the other comments. Anybody know if this switch still exists, and if not what another workaround is?

Comment: No builds are available in Testflight tab, even though I'm able to see builds in Activity tab. Anyone found solution?

Comment: Oct 2018 here... Y had uploaded 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 build. Last shown under 'testflight' tab was 3... Builds 4, 5 and 6 never appeared... I expired 1, 2 and 3 under testflight tab and then build 6 appeared there.

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua Yap, removing and readding the tester did the trick for us.

Comment: Removing and re-adding testers worked for me as well.

Answer (score 13):

Check also if you compiled the app with the right certificate.
I got the same issue when uploading a binary compiled with the wrong one (Ad Hoc instead of App Store). App Loader and iTunes didn't complain, but the binary wasn't visible for selection in TestFlight.

Comment: This was my issue, so used to uploading builds with AdHoc profiles for testing that I didn't even think twice about it. Would be easy enough for Apple to catch this you'd have thought. No message or nothing!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and the toggle answer didn't work. I had to remove myself as an internal tester and then invite myself agin. After entering the redeem code into the TestFlight App it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same issue and I went to the **iTunesConnect website** -> **My Apps** -> **Selected my app** -> **Opened the TestFlight tab** -> **clicked on the build number**.

After that, in a few seconds the app showed up in the TestFlight app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Mine is like that. I always have to click on the TestFlight tab so as to receive a notification immediately. How to solve that?

Comment: report please  a bug to apple.  https://bugreport.apple.com/. I did it and received response that it is duplicate of already existing bug, but it is in open state. May be the more bug reports are opened the higher priority apple devs will set to this issue

Comment: I also have this issue. They said they fixed it, but they didn't. Hopefully they'll get more bugs from others.

Answer (score 7):

I tried everything and non worked, for me the following worked:

TestFlight > App Store Connect Users > Testers Tab

I removed the people in the list and added them again. an email was for the first time sent to them including the "view in testflight" button which is what we want!

before this I had filled out the required forms and questions asked by apple in order to run testflihght.

Comment: I did this and I am always getting the previous build not the new Build. I have expired the previous build also but still I am getting the previous build. Please help

Comment: @Tarun check your build number and version, publish a new build after you see the new build in App Store Connect continue the steps for the new build and you should get the new build in test fight.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, which seems to have become quite frequent recently (Feb 2020). [See here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/104035)

Adding `App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption = NO` to my app's info.plist, a subsequent upload to iTunes Connect worked and the app appeared in TestFlight. This is a recent bug/change by Apple as prior releases worked with TestFlight after providing the export compliance information in iTunes Connect.

For more information on this entry in the info.plist and export compliance [see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations).

Comment: Thanks for this. I had tried uploading 3 different binaries and the on 4th attempt I added details to the info.plist as suggested and bingo....it worked.

Comment: It works for me in 2021

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Once I complete the Export Compliance certificate I was able to see the app in TestFlight. There is a high chance that your app may also need to complete it.

In iTunes Connect, go to *TestFlight (Tab) > iOS (Sidemenu) > iOS Builds* select the latest build and complete the Export Compliance.

On iPhone / iPad - open the TestFlight app > Select your app > Tap into Previous builds - you will be able to see all builds and choose whichever you want to test.

Happy Testing!

Answer (score 3):

If your latest build still doesn't show on Test Flight, **open your email** that has received an invitation for testing. Usually, you will receive an **invitation** from TestFlight.

This email contains an **open TestFlight** link. I recommend that you **login your email on your Mail app**. This will automatically open TestFlight and display the latest build.

Answer (score 3):

March 2020 solution for me was to both:

1. Add "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption" to "NO" in info.plist
2. Increment the Version, not just the build

Answer (score 3):

if somebody is still facing this issue, that build is not getting displayed in testflight and xcode showing build successful. Then do check your mail id which is linked with the apple developer account.

Sometimes the issues lies with some missing keys in Info.plist file. So what happen is xcode shows that the build is uploaded but the binary is invalid thats why testflight doesn't show it.

In that case apple sends you a mail in which they specifically tells what is missing in the info.plist file.
After adding all the keys everything will work fine.

Comment: This seems to be the issue recently

Answer (score 2):

It is because of your build version is lower than one of your previous builds. You can re-upload highest version of your older builds or you can download before waiting from the mobile app (test flight app) with following steps:

- go to test flight mobile app.
- click on your latest/current app (it will show you the details of the app).
- click on the "Previous Builds".
- install your version from here.

Comment: My build not coming in previous builds

Answer (score 2):

**14-08-2018**

*This is my workflow*

> iTunesConnect website -> My Apps -> Selected my app -> Opened the
>   TestFlight tab -> clicked on the build number -> Test Details --> Fill
>   what to Test box --> Save

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem al the time as well and for us it is enough to click on the TestFlight tab in itunes connect and the build always appears immediately in TestFlight with a notification

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I only had to log out from App Store Connect Web application and then log in again. When then went to TestFlight tab the build was there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Apple orders versions by number of digits before the value itself. So 0.62 shows up higher than 0.7, and this affects TestFlight as well.

For us it was a simple fix: label the version with the same number of digits every time!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons as of 09/2020:

1. TestFlight > App Store Connect Users, remove all of them, add back in
2. Check if your app has the right cert
3. Make sure you accept Itunes Connect Agreement Updates. (This was my issue, the dialog did not pop up)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this issue in 2020, do check if you have added the build for external testing by:

1. Going to App Store Connect, TestFlight Tab
2. On the left panel under External Groups -> iPhone Testers go to build and add your latest build.
   3 The app will now be available to your testers on TestFlight

Comment: This worked for me. I was using only individual testers and it was not working. When I added the same testers to a group and added a group, it immediately updated the Testflight app to show the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

## Not Your Fault

Remember, sometimes it's just a Server error. Before trying the other answers, please check Apple's [System Status web page](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/).

For example, in my case check the image for the current status.

- Even if the testflight doesn't show an issue right now, as you can see there is an issue marked for the App Store Connect Performance.
- Rarely, I might need to re-send my application.
- Usually fixes automatically after a while.

[image: Apple System Status]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding the beta-reports-active entitlement. As soon as I added this the next build showed up for in itunes connect.

< key >beta-reports-active< /key >

< false/ >

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having the issue where the new update is not going out to your testers, what I did was click on the update I wanted to send out and next to the button that says Expire build I clicked notify testers that refreshed their TestFlight and sent out the new update.

Answer (score 0):

This also occurs if you click on the TestFlight tab BEFORE your current  version has had a BUILD selected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, reloaded the page and found latest version was shown.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

It didn't show in TestFlight build until I incremented the app version from 1.0 to 1.1

So try incrementing current version and build.

[image: version]

Answer (score 0):

Remove tester from tester list in itunes and add again. 
Refresh test flight app on mobile and then you can see the new update.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a tester, and re-adding the tester solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

upload a new build with the new version and build no. It solved my problem.
I was also facing the same issue. My build was showing in testflight but not showing in app-store for submission. So I uploaded a new build with the new version and build number and solved my problem.
Xcode -> YourTarget-> General (tab) -> Version / Build.

Answer (score 0):

If it not showing after some time also then it means there is an error. Check your email apple team sends failure reasons

Answer (score -2):

This workflow was the unique that works for me.

iTunesConnect website -> My Apps -> Selected my app -> Opened the TestFlight tab -> clicked on the build number -> Test Details --> Fill what to Test box --> Save