# Xcode build not showing up on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying to upload my app to TestFlight. I have created new provisioning profiles and have code signed the app as following:

[image: Code signing]

In Xcode, the app successfully uploads to iTunes Connect, and soon after, I see the "processing build" screen on the Activity tab on iTunes Connect:

[image: loading]

A few minutes later, the processing build disappears and there are no builds on the screen. I am unable to select a build as it simply says, *Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later.*. How can I find the build on iTunes Connect? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370285/latest-itunes-connect-build-not-showing-in-test-flight ?

Comment: @matt this is my first version and it hasn't shown up

Comment: @penatheboss How long did you wait? It sometimes can take a couple of hours for a build to process. If it's in the "Activity" tab, just wait until it finishes...

Comment: @Oddie ive tried this multiple times over the past few days and none have worked. The problem is that it disappears from the activity tab

Answer (score 1):

My solution... is terrible, but I have found success uploading builds until they show up. It sometimes takes like 30 uploads, and other times it only takes one. This problem is affecting every build I have tried since I switched to Xcode 8 in December. It's horribly inefficient but it's the only thing I have found that works.

EDIT: Right after I sent this answer, I got my build processed at upload 13. Good luck, buddy.

Comment: @matt for all the unaccounted failings of submissions and down servers, it might as well be an answer.  Although I agree with you, I don't see how to get any solid results.  I'm currently waiting for a response back from Apple about why my submission hasn't appeared for 72 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem With **xCode 9**.

The reason behind it was, the new icon we have to include in `App Icon` for `App Store (1024 * 1024)` was in *.jpg format instead of .png*.

Here is the mail, I received from Apple.

```
Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "MyAppName". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid Image - For iOS applications, icons included in the binary submission must be in the PNG format.

If your application supports the iPhone device family, you must include square icons of the following dimensions: 57x57 pixels.
If your application supports the iPad device family, you must include square icons of the following dimensions: 72x72 pixels.
For macOS applications, icons included in the binary submission must be in the ICNS format and must include a square 512x512@2x image.
Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team
```

So my advice is

- Look into your/client's mail box, you must have received email from Apple regarding the issue
- Make sure you have included every image file in .png format
- Make sure you have included every privacy description correct regarding the exact usage

For example, for Location usage description, instead of `"App would like to use location"`, please write something like `"Location is required for driver  to find out where you are as well as for nearby suggestions."`

Answer (score 0):

Add missing items in `info.plist`, such as icon files, privacy usage description, requirements etc. It works for me.