# Getting IOS app in test flight

Tags: ios, testflight

guys, we outsourced our mobile app development and the company is just giving me an IPA file that I have to re-sign then upload it to iTunes connect. Now I only want to see this app in test flight I watched a youtube video thought it would be straightforward so I created a production certificate after I did my app id then I created a distribution provisioning profile and selected app store as my distribution. I used to design in order to change everything I found this tutorial [here](http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/) but when I use application loader and submit the app into iTunes connect I have a choice to use that build to send for review in the app store but I cannot choose this build in a test flight. Here are some pics where it shows my build in the activity but I can't select this build in a test flight. I am a noob when it comes to this so any help would be great. Also every time I upload this I have to ask them to change the build string and re-send back to me which is getting annoying

[image: testflight]

[image: activity]

Comment: I can see two builds in your screen shot.  Are those not the builds you are looking for?

Comment: @josh check your user role in iTunesConnect, you probably don't have permissions to submit an app for review. It should be at least *App Manager*.

Developer Role - Can upload a build, but can't submit it for review.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I would like to submit one of those builds they are actually the same.

Comment: @Satish I did check my role and I am an admin so I have legal, admin, finance, app manager, developer, marketer, sales, customer support, repots all of them are checked

Answer (score 0):

Two type of testers in TestFlight

1. iTunes connect the user 
   In this case, you have seen when you have submitted build after processing completes, you have asked to complete compliance ( Wheather this app contains encryption or not etc ). Once it is done it available to testers immediately.

[image]

2. Non-iTunes connect user

In this case you have to select testers group and select build tab. after this select "+" option

[image]

After this, you will be shown a dialog to select build and proceed with the submission process.

[image]

You should be at least "App Manager" for this app.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have all of these roles checked legal, admin, finance, app manager, developer, marketer, sales, customer support and reports. I did try to do what you said for the external users, but when I hit the + button they do not show me any builds for me to select. If I go to the app store tabe and go down to prepare for submission I am able to select a build from there but not in test flight. I do not know about asking to complete compliance I am just adding people that are part of my organization for ituness connect users.

Comment: Might sound irrelevant, but can you try with browser cache clean or on some other browser. Other facing same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370285/latest-itunes-connect-build-not-showing-in-testflight

Comment: I have tried both chrome and safari and refreshed I did all of this while on the phone with apple support. I even tried on my windows pc but still the same thing

Comment: it is really weird because when I click on test flight and ios on the left hand side it says version2.0 is ready to test... it has version 2.0 with a blue arrow If I click that arrow I get nothing